# How to display an integer many times

Tags: python, string, input, integer, display

I'd like to create a function that add 2 to an integer as much as we want. It would look like that:

```
>>> n = 3 
>>> add_two(n)
Would you like to add a two to n ? Yes
The new n is 5
Would you like to add a two to n ? Yes
the new n is 7
Would you like to add a two to n ? No
```

Can anyone help me please ? I don't how I can print the sentence without recalling the function.

Comment: The thing you're looking for is a 'while' statement.

Comment: thank you it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use a `while` loop within your function that continues to add two each time you tell it to. Otherwise, it exits.

Given that knowledge, I'd suggest trying it yourself first but I'll provide a solution below that you can compare yours against.

---

That solution *could* be as simple as:

```py
while input("Would you like to add a two to n ?") == "Yes":
    n += 2
    print(f"the new n is {n}")
```

---

But, since  I rarely miss an opportunity to improve on code, I'll provide a more sophisticated solution as well, with the following differences:

- It prints the starting number before anything else;
- It allows an arbitrary number to be added, defaulting to two if none provided;
- The output text is slightly more human-friendly;
- It requires a yes or no answer (actually anything starting with upper or lower-case `y` or `n` will do, everything else is ignored and the question is re-asked).

```py
def add_two(number, delta = 2):
    print(f"The initial number is {number}")

    # Loop forever, relying on break to finish adding.

    while True:
        # Ensure responses are yes or no only (first letter, any case).

        response = ""
        while response not in ["y", "n"]:
            response = input(f"Would you like to add {delta} to the number? ")[:1].lower()

        # Finish up if 'no' selected.

        if response == "n":
            break

        # Otherwise, add value, print it, and continue.

        number += delta
        print(f"The new number is {number}")

# Incredibly basic/deficient test harness :-)

add_two(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use looping in your `add_two()` function. So, your function can print the sentence without recalling the function.

Answer (score 1):

The above answer describes in detail what to do and why, if you're looking for very simple beginner-type code that covers your requirements, try this:

```py
n = 3

while True:
    inp = input("Would you like to add 2 to n? Enter 'yes'/'no'. To exit, type 'end' ")
    if inp == "yes":
        n = n + 2
    elif inp == "no":
        None
    elif inp == "end":      # if the user wants to exit the loop
        break
    else:
        print("Error in input")     # simple input error handling
    print("The new n is: ", n)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can wrap it in a function. The function breaks once the yes condition is not met

```
def addd(n):
    while n:
        inp = input('would like to add 2 to n:' )
        if inp.lower() == 'yes':
            n = n + 2
            print(f'The new n is {n}')
        else:
            return

addd(10)
```